# Manuscript status is in "Revise and Resubmit" with only 1 reviewer's comment

Tags: publications, peer-review

Manuscript submitted in an elsevier journal is now in "Revise and Resubmit" status. Journal editor provided only one reviewer's comments. The comments suggested some minor changes only and revision time is given 2 weeks.
What do you guys think? What's the possibility of getting rejected?

Comment: I'm well aware of the publication process, I'm just confused with the single reviewer's comment & short time given for revision. Will the manuscript be rejected anyway?

Comment: This is not a confusing or unusual situation.  Maybe not typical, but not unusual.

Comment: From what you say, it seems likely that the paper will be accepted.

Comment: @GEdgar, actually such a assumption is unwarranted. It could still be rejected for any reason or no reason at all. All you can safely conclude is that the process continues. But the feedback is encouraging, at least.

Comment: @Buffy i second that. It just says that changes are necessary. Revise and resubmit could be closer to a rejection than to an acceptance. It depends on the journals' policy (which categories they have)

Comment: @Buffy Balderdash. No sane editor forwards reviewer comments asking for nothing but minor revisions if he actually thinks the paper is bad and should be rejected.

Comment: @Karl, Balderdash back atcha. The editor will make a judgement on the final version. And only on the final version and will make it in relationship to other things they have.

Comment: Chances of rejection are almost not existing. Unless you ruin the paper by minor revising it :))

Comment: I'm with @Buffy.  I've been a referee in circumstances where a minor improvement to the clarity of a manuscript revealed major (and hitherto unsuspected) problems with its substance.